# Can't figure out complex query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Could anybody point me in the direction of how to write a complex mysql query? I am familiar with joins, views, and intermediate querying, but cannot quite conceptualise how to go about writing a query to pull out the data I am looking for.

I have three tables, user, user_category and category. user_category is just a bridge table.

```
user

user_id   name         
-----------------------
1         Bob
2         Tim
3         Dave
4         Simon
5         Ben

user_category

user_id   category_id
-----------------------
1         1
1         5
1         3
2         4
2         1
3         2
3         4
4         4
4         1
5         3
5         5

category

category_id  category   
-----------------------
1            drawing    
2            climbing     
3            hunting    
4            fishing    
5            sleeping
```

So I can easily pull out a list of users in each category, no problem.

What I want to do, for each of these categories, is show a list of other categories that the list of users in this category is also in.

So if I take fishing as an example, my query would pull out Tim, Dave and Simon as being in that category. I want to list all the other categories that Tim Dave and Simon are in, with a count of how many users are in each of those categories. Like this:

```
Drawing (2) - this has Tim and Simon in it
Climbing (1) - this has Dave in it
```

I realise I need to get a list of users in a given category. Simple.

I also need a list of all the categories that each of these users is in (excluding current category).

Then for each category, I need a count of each of the users in each.

I think I could write this with separate nested queries, but I would like to write this in a single query using all the necessary joins if possible, but if anyone can point me towards some reading material or video content that would help me work out how to plan these queries, that would be even better.

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: As I mentioned, If I select Fishing as the category, I would expect to return an array with two categories and a number of users in each of those: Drawing (2) - this has Tim and Simon in it and Climbing (1) - this has Dave in it

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization. Please show parts you can do. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Asking for outside resources is off-topic. But--Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design & querying textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. PS Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without site:stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple joins of the tables:

```
select cn.category, count(*) counter
from category c
inner  join user_category uc on uc.category_id = c.category_id
inner join user u on u.user_id = uc.user_id
inner join user_category ucn 
on ucn.user_id = u.user_id and ucn.category_id <> uc.category_id
inner join category cn on cn.category_id = ucn.category_id
where c.category = 'Fishing'
group by cn.category
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aUFvnHiNe6RJUqC6JtYp8Q/3).
Results:

```
| category | counter |
| -------- | ------- |
| climbing | 1       |
| drawing  | 2       |
```

Comment: That's phenomenal. - any recommended reading or online courses that can help me learn how you worked this approach out?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recommend online courses. Just study anything about SQL and here in SO you will find plenty of good material.

Comment: Great solution! Maybe a further simplification could be achieved by removing the `inner join user u on u.user_id = uc.user_id` line and replacing the reference to `u.user_id`with `uc.user_id` in the following `ON` clause, see here for a demo:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aUFvnHiNe6RJUqC6JtYp8Q/4 (modified from forpas's original fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

With this query, you get your data, if you want a specific hobby, add a where clause for c.category = 'fishing' for example

```
SELECT 
    MIN(c.category), COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(`name`)
FROM 
    user_category uc  
INNER JOIN 
    user u ON uc.user_id = u.user_id 
INNER JOIN
    category c ON uc.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY 
    uc.category_id
```

This returns the following result:

```
MIN(c.category)     Count(*)    GROUP_CONCAT(`name`)
drawing             3           Bob,Tim,Simon
climbing            1           Dave
hunting             2           Ben,Bob
fishing             3           Tim,Dave,Simon
sleeping            2           Bob,Ben
```

DBfiddle example
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ad26cf2ab673d349f82d8875022af2aa